# Unable to import zpool after accidental hibernation on FDE system (acer aspire 7)

Tags: boot, encryption, hibernate, initramfs

I'm on a full disk encrypted (FDE) Ubuntu 22.04 Due to low battery, my notebook went into hibernation (which most likely isn't properly implemented with FDE). As I'm trying to boot, I get the error: cannot import 'rpool'.
Manually importing via zpool import -n 'rpool' or similar commands won't work. Is there any way to discard the hibernation boot and go back to a regular boot? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I figured out what happened, incredible as it sounds:
After the hibernation shutdown due to low energy, the BIOS settings got messed up changing the disk controller to RST rather than AHCI. So the solution for me was to change the BIOS settings back to ACHI and booting works normally.